# Traducción: el comentario automático en cierre por "gracias" está en inglés

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

En la cola de revisión, al votar por cerrar una respuesta porque es un agradecimiento a otra respuesta, se genera el siguiente comentario automático:

[image: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that you found most helpful.]

Enlace: [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/21598/127) (luego de la revisión, edité el comentario para que aparezca en español)

### Propuesta:

> Por favor, no añadas "gracias" como respuesta. En cambio, **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** que pienses que es la mejor solución a tu problema.

`Por favor, no añadas "gracias" como respuesta. En cambio, **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** que pienses que es la mejor solución a tu problema.`

Comment: `Por favor, no añadas "gracias" como respuesta. En cambio, [acepta la respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) que te ayudó más para resolver tu problema` (Otra propuesta parecida, la primera parte la encuentro mejor, la segunda es indiferente).

Comment: @MiquelColl `no añadas` es una forma más lejana a como hablo, pero te lo acepto para que concuerde con el resto de los textos del sitio. La segunda parte está tomada de http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ... la dejó así (en todo caso se debería evaluar cambiarlo en ambos lados)

Comment: Tienes razón, a mi me suena mejor el `no añadas` pero por mi posición geográfica haha. Quizá es mejor que propongas ambas opciones y la comunidad elija :)

Comment: Olvidate! Sería imposible que nos pongamos de acuerdo en el uso del español :) ... Igual, cuando leí tu comentario, me acordé que ya habían puesto `no añadas` en otro lado (no me acuerdo dónde). Mejor dejarlo coherente con el resto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta cadena estaba traducida en Transifex pero no había sido marcada como revisada, quizá por despiste del traductor. La acabo de marcar, así que la traducción será visible tras la próxima compilación.

Comment: Respuesta votada y aceptada a los pocos segundos de su publicación. A ver, en serio, ¿no tenéis vida? :-D

Comment: Las notificaciones en el celular funcionan bien :)

Comment: [vote early, vote often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/) :-P

Comment: @Mariano sobretodo en la página principal!